# verificar se o dia existe ou não com o if

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso verificar se o dia não existe... faz insert, se sim, faz update.

Deixo o exemplo na prática do que preciso:

```
if(ver se existe no banco){ 

.....if(){ 

..........faz insert 
.....} 

}else{ 

.... faz updade 

}
```

O código que tenho:

```
if(!empty($_POST['arrachar'])){     
// Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox. 
foreach($_POST['arrachar'] as $selected){   
$string = implode(',', $selected);

preg_match('/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/', $string, $dia); 
$dia = $dia[0];
$sq="SELECT Id, arrachar FROM centrodb.marcacao WHERE LOCATE('$dia', arrachar) > 0";;
$r1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sq);
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($r1)) {
    $id_do_registro = $rows_cursos['Id'];
}
if(!$id_do_registro){
if(preg_match('/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/', $string)){
$sql="INSERT INTO marcacao (arrachar) VALUES ('".$string."')";
$r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

}else{ $sql1 = "UPDATE marcacao SET arrachar = '$string' WHERE Id = '$id_do_registro'";
$rs = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
}
}    
}
}
```

Não está a funcionar corretamente, porque só faz o insert uma vez, depois de ter dados na tabela da base de dados não insere novamente e não faz o update.

Penso que o problema estará aqui, `if(!$id_do_registro){` porque depois de inserir valores na base de dados não volta a inserir nem faz o update

Este é o meu html:

```
$calendar .= "<td bgcolor='#F5F5F5' align='center' data-semana=''><center><font size='2px'/> 
<input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][dia]' value='$year-$month-$day' $marcado_data $disabled> $year-$month-$day <br /> 
<input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq_Almoço' $marcado_pequeno $disabled> Peq. Almoço <input $disabled type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd]' value='$marcado_pequeno_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> 
<input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoB]' value='Almoço' $marcado_almoco $disabled> Almoço <input $disabled type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd1]' value='$marcado_almoco_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> 
<input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoC]' value='Almoço_(Dieta)' $marcado_dieta $disabled> Almoço (Dieta) <input $disabled type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd2]' value='$marcado_dieta_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> 
<input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoD]' value='Lanche' $marcado_lanche $disabled> Lanche <input $disabled type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd3]' value='$marcado_lanche_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /><br /> 
<input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoE]' value='Jantar' $marcado_jantar $disabled> Jantar <input $disabled type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd4]' value='$marcado_jantar_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> 
<input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoF]' value='Jantar_(Dieta)' $marcado_jantardie $disabled> Jantar (Dieta) <input $disabled type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd5]' value='$marcado_jantardie_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> </font></center></td>";

}
```

Comment: Testa sem a exclamação: `if($id_do_registro) { ...`

Comment: Sem o ponto de exclamação volta a inserir como novas linhas as que devia fazer update e insere os novos registos que fiz, o problema neste momento é que não faz o update

Comment: Coloca `echo`s em vários lugares e veja se as variáveis estão corretas e aonde ele está entrando (`if` ou `else`), teste também o script SQL direto no phpMyAdmin ou algo assim para ter certeza que não faltou ou sobrou alguma letra em alguma coluna

Comment: `while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($r1)) {
    $id_do_registro = $rows_cursos['Id'];
} echo $id_do_registro;
if(!$id_do_registro){` retorna 186187188185185188188. Está a funcionar

Comment: `if(!$id_do_registro){
 echo $id_do_registro;
 echo $string;
if(preg_match('/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/', $string)){` aqui coloquei estes dois echos mas não retorna nada nem insere

Comment: Coloque um `echo $id_do_registro` antes do `if`

Comment: while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($r1)) { $id_do_registro = $rows_cursos['Id']; } echo $id_do_registro; if(!$id_do_registro){ retorna 186187188185185188188.

Comment: Antes do insert coloquei estes echos `echo $id_do_registro; echo $string; 
$sql="INSERT INTO marcacao (arrachar) VALUES ('".$string."')";` e detetei um problema. Os ids do que já está registado na tabela estão corretos no que retorna 1822018-04-24,Peq_Almoço,10,Almoço,10,,Lanche,10,,1832018-04-25,,,,Lanche,15,Jantar,15,1842018-04-26,Peq_Almoço,12,Almoço,12,,,,**185**2018-04-27,,,,Lanche,14,Jantar,14, mas no novo registo volta a repetir o id como mostro **185**2018-04-28,Peq_Almoço,10,Almoço,10,,,, onde este id devia ser 324 que foi o id que ficou na tabela

Comment: @Iniciante tenta do jeito que eu fiz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você estava tentando fazer `UPDATE` dentro do `IF` que verifica se não existe `ID`. Não vai fazer update pois o id não existe. O certo é esse código estar em um ELSE deste IF. Tipo isso:

```
if(!$id_do_registro){ // se não existir id do registro
    // inclua
} else {
   // muda através do id
}
```

Além disso, tem o erro no seu while, também citado pelo @fernando.

**EDIT**

Conforme conversado no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76434/room-for-iniciante-and-andrei-coelho)

Seu código ficará assim:

```
if(!empty($_POST['arrachar'])){     
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox. 
    $stringSelect = "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 1) as data, Id, arrachar FROM marcacao WHERE ";
    $stringNew = "INSERT INTO marcacao (arrachar) VALUES ";
    $arrayValues = array();
    $statusNew = false;
    foreach($_POST['arrachar'] as $selected){

        $string = implode(',', $selected);
        $vazio = str_replace(",","",$string);
        $date = explode(",",$string);
        $data = $date[0];
        if($vazio != ""){
            $stringSelect .= "SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 1) = '$data' OR ";
            $arrayValues[] = array(
                "data" => $data,
                "arrachar" => $string
            );
        }

    }
    $stringSelect = substr($stringSelect, 0, -3);
    $r1 = mysqli_query($conn,$stringSelect) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $index = array();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($r1) > 0){
        while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($r1)){
            for($i=0; $i < count($arrayValues); $i++){
                if($rows_cursos['data'] == $arrayValues[$i]['data']){
                    if($rows_cursos['arrachar'] != $arrayValues[$i]['arrachar']){
                        $id = $rows_cursos['Id'];
                        $strin = $arrayValues[$i]['arrachar'];
                        $sql1 = "UPDATE marcacao SET arrachar = '$strin' WHERE Id = '$id'";
                        $rs = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));                        
                    }
                    $index[] = $i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(isset($arrayValues[0])){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayValues); $i++){
            if(!in_array($i,$index)){
                $stringNew .= "('".$arrayValues[$i]['arrachar']."'),";
                $statusNew = true;
            }
        }

        if($statusNew){
            $stringNew = substr($stringNew, 0, -1);
            mysqli_query($conn,$stringNew) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Não insere nada na tabela da base de dados desta forma nem `if(!$id_do_registro){` e nem `if($id_do_registro){`

Comment: @Iniciante tenta agora

Comment: Também não insere nem de uma forma nem da outra, podemos falar no chat para explicar melhor o que pretendo e a ideia do que tenho aí no código?

Comment: @Iniciante sim... podemos

Comment: @Iniciante deu certo?

Answer (score 3):

Você tem um problema no uso das variáveis. Verifique por exemplo que dentro de um while você faz uma atribuição de valores em uma variável:

```
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($r1)) {
    $id_do_registro = $rows_cursos['Id'];
}
```

O $id_do_registro sempre vai receber o último registro do índice 'Id' do array $rows_cursos.

O IF é para ser simples, como colocado no código mas você precisa das variáveis certas para isso.

Possivelmente você teria que incluir o IF dentro do While mas sem maiores informações sobre parâmetros enviados não há como analisar melhor.

Veja como ficaria:

```
if(!empty($_POST['arrachar'])){     
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox. 
    foreach($_POST['arrachar'] as $selected){
        $string = implode(',', $selected);

        preg_match('/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/', $string, $dia);
        $dia = $dia[0];
        $sq="SELECT Id, arrachar FROM centrodb.marcacao WHERE LOCATE('$dia', arrachar) > 0";;
        $r1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sq);
        while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($r1)) {
            $id_do_registro = $rows_cursos['Id'];
            if(!$id_do_registro){
                if(preg_match('/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/', $string)){
                    $sql="INSERT INTO marcacao (arrachar) VALUES ('".$string."')";
                    $r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

                }else{ $sql1 = "UPDATE marcacao SET arrachar = '$string' WHERE Id = '$id_do_registro'";
                    $rs = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Indique no código a lógica usada que facilita para perceber o que se passa. O ideal seria ter tudo separado com um método que trataria de inserir os registros na BD. Nesse método ele receberia um registro ou um array de registros (depende do negócio) e para cada um (dentro de um loop) faria a verificação se já existe para fazer update ou senão faz o insert.

Comment: podemos falar pelo chat?

Comment: Não funcionou, com o `if(!$id_do_registro){` não insere nada na tabela da base de dados, então alterei para `if($id_do_registro){` e colocou as linhas todas vazias existentes na base de dados